# Email template styles are not working

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, css, email-templates, styles

I've not changed the core header.html which is in the vendor directory.

According to the Magento 2 dev docs, I must create **"email-inline.less"** in **app/design/MyVendor/MyTheme/web/css** directory, however, the styles are not being applied to the sent email.

I'm wondering if **email-inline.less** file will be compiled automatically or I have to compile it first to the css file? I've actually made seperate **email-inline.css** file, but styles were not working with this one too.

Answer (score 1):

The file name should have an underscore prefix: **_email-inline.less** 
After writing your styles you should remove static files

```
rm -rf var/view_preprocessed/* pub/static/*
```

Answer (score 0):

Please add email-inline.css instead of  email-inline.less on

app/design/MyVendor/MyTheme/web/css

Answer (score 0):

Please try to add `important` on your custom css changes because if Magento default CSS priority before your CSS in that case you changes not reflected so please check with `important`.

Here is example for you reference.

```
background-color: red !important;
```

Hope it will work for you!

Answer (score 0):

Please add your css in _email.less file. Below is the file path.

```
app/design/frontend/{themename}/{namespace}/web/css/source/_email.less
```

If _email.less is not exists on this file then copy it from the parent theme.